# how to copy emacs version info and org-mode version info?

Tags: help

Is there a command to display and automatically copy to clipboard both the current version of Emacs and the current version of org-mode?

Comment: That's pretty idiosyncratic, so you'll probably need to write it yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: Here's what I have. Doesn't work. 

`(defun display-and-copy-version-info ()
 "Echo the current version of Spacemacs, Emacs, and org-mode, and copy it."
 (interactive)
 (let ((msg (format "Spacemacs v.%s" spacemacs-version "Emacs" emacs-version "org-mode" org-version)))
  (message msg) (clipboard-kill-ring-save msg)))` 

I feel like it would be useful to anyone who needs to submit issues for any package that's org-mode related.

Comment: @incandescentman it looks like you're confusing between  `concat` and `format`.

Comment: @npostavs When I change it to concat I get `edebug-read-sexp: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’`

Comment: hmm, I get `error: "Not enough arguments for format string"`, and after fixing the `message` call, `Wrong number of arguments` for the `clipboard-kill-ring-save` call. I think you want `(let ((select-enable-clipboard t)) (kill-new msg))`.

Comment: @npostavs Like this? `(defun display-and-copy-version-info ()
 "Echo the current version of Spacemacs, Emacs, and org-mode, and copy it."
 (interactive) 
 (let ((msg (concat "Spacemacs v.%s" spacemacs-version "Emacs" emacs-version "org-mode" org-version))) 
  (message msg) 
(let ((select-enable-clipboard t)) (kill-new msg)) 
))`

Comment: @incandescentman does that work for you? I need `(message %s msg)` to run without error.

Comment: @npostavs No, I still get `let: Not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: Not directly related, but may of interest in this context: the *functions* `emacs-version` and `org-version` take a prefix argument which says "put the output in this buffer". So if you are composing your bug report in emacs, all you have to do is `C-u M-x emacs-version` and `C-u M-x org-version` and you are done. You can also wrap the two calls into a single function of course, or bind them to keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the doc string for function `format`, with `C-h f format` (`M-x describe-function`). It is similar to the C language `printf`, if you know that.  The doc string for message includes:

> (message FORMAT-STRING &rest ARGS)
>
> Display a message at the bottom of the screen.
>   The message also goes into the ‘*Messages*’ buffer, if ‘message-log-max’
>   is non-nil.  (In keyboard macros, that’s all it does.)
>   Return the message.

Also, the docstring for `clipboard-kill-ring-save` shows you don't call it with the proper arguments, and in fact is to be used when copying some text from a buffer, not from a string.

Searching for "kill-ring" in the index of the info elisp manual can bring to the section [Low-Level Kill Ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring.html#Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring) where the function `kill-new` is described.  Since `message` returns the displayed string, we can feed it directly to `kill-new`.

```el
(defun display-and-copy-version-info ()
  "Echo the current version of Spacemacs, Emacs, and org-mode, and copy it."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new
     (message "Spacemacs v.%s Emacs %s org-mode %s"
              spacemacs-version emacs-version org-version)))
```

Comment: You should use `(message "%s" msg)` to be safe (probably none of the versions will include a `%` so it doesn't really matter, but still...)

Comment: @npostavs Indeed, thanx.